# Automatic image scaling to percentage of screen width inside Android layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'd like to reproduce the following layout. [image]

But I can't reproduce correctly the area inside red rectangle. Code so far:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/graph_bg" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.13">
    </View>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.74">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/pic_mw_logo" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/calcs"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.13">
    </View>

</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sponsored_descr"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Sponsored by\nxxxx"/>
<!--- LOGOS HERE I SUPPOSE -->        

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Both logos at the bottom are pictures with size about 200x100 px. I'd like them to be scaled to say about 15% of screen width each and displayed like on the picture

Comment: Maybe it's a good idea to simply make "Sponsored by" and logo a single image, but I hope it can be done inside xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [PercentRelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html) instead of simple `RelativeLayout` and just add `app:layout_heightPercent` property with the percentage which you want. As it's a part of support libraries you should add `compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.0.1'` to your gradle dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `LinearLayout` and set empty `View` components around and give them the `layout_weight` property.

If you need 15% of the screen size, set the `LinearLayout`'s width to `match_parent`, set `weightSum` to `100` and give the image the `weight` `15`. Make sure to set the blank `View`s you have to complete the weight to 100.